# ASP.NET Line Chart C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a line chart in my asp.net web app, but it's not displaying. Can anyone help me with this? I'm new to making charts in C#. I have the complete code for generating the chart below. The Flexible_Straight_Button calls the FlexibleStraightButton_Click method. this method calls the Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart. The Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart method looks like it's generating the chart correctly, but it's not displaying the actual chart on the app.

HTML Code

```
<asp:Button Text="ACN and ACR Calculations" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab1" CssClass="Initial"
    OnClick="Tab1_Click" />
<asp:Button Text="Aircraft Landing Gear" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab2" CssClass="Initial"
    OnClick="Tab2_Click"/>
<asp:MultiView ID="MainView" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ACN_ACR_Label" runat="server" Text="ACN Table"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Progress" runat="server" Text="Click the button below to start."></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:GridView ID="ACN_ACR_Table" runat="server" ShowHeader="false">
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button Text="Generate ACN Table" ID="Generate_Table" runat="server" Width="336px" OnClick="Generate_Table_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Chart ID="Chart" runat="server">
                        <series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                            </asp:Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series2">
                            </asp:Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series3">
                            </asp:Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series4">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </series>
                        <chartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                            </asp:ChartArea>
                        </chartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>

</table>
        </td>
        <td>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: large" class="auto-style1">

                        <asp:Label ID="Flexible_Chart_Label" runat="server" Text="Generate Flexible ACN Charts"></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                </tr>                        
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: medium">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Flexible_Straight_Button" runat="server" Text="Straight Lines" Width="183px" Height="27px" OnClick="FlexibleStraightButton_Click" />
                        <br />

                    </td>
                </tr>                        
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: medium">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Flexible_Curves_Button" runat="server" Text="Curves" Width="183px" Height="27px" Enabled="False" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="auto-style4">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: large" class="auto-style1">

                        <asp:Label ID="Rigid_Chart_Label" runat="server" Text="Generate Rigid ACN Charts"></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                </tr>                        
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: medium">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Rigid_Straight_Button" runat="server" Text="Straight Lines" Width="183px" Height="27px" Enabled="False" />
                        <br />

                    </td>
                </tr>                        
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: medium">

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Rigid_Curves_Button" runat="server" Text="Curves" Width="183px" Height="27px" Enabled="False" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

C# Code

```
protected void FlexibleStraightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vehicle = new Vehicle();
    OleDbConnection connection = null;
    string vehicleName = null;

    Get_Vehicle_Data(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

    Get_Tire_Data(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

    Get_Evaluation_Points(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

    if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
    }
    else if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
    {
        Generate_Flexible_ACR_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
    }
}

private void Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart(ref Vehicle vehicle)
{
    /*       flexibleMinACNs = new double[4];
           flexibleMaxACNs = new double[4];

           ICAO.CalculateFlexibleACN(vehicle, vehicle.MinLoad, flexibleMinACNs);
           ICAO.CalculateFlexibleACN(vehicle, vehicle.MaxLoad, flexibleMaxACNs);

           Chart.Titles.Add("Flexible ACN Straight Line Chart");
           Chart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
           Chart.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
           Chart.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
           Chart.Series["Series4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

           Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MinLoad, flexibleMinACNs[0]);
           Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MaxLoad, flexibleMaxACNs[0]);

           Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MinLoad, flexibleMinACNs[1]);
           Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MaxLoad, flexibleMaxACNs[1]);

           Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MinLoad, flexibleMinACNs[2]);
           Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MaxLoad, flexibleMaxACNs[2]);

           Chart.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MinLoad, flexibleMinACNs[3]);
           Chart.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY(vehicle.MaxLoad, flexibleMaxACNs[3]);*/

    Chart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    Chart.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    Chart.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    Chart.Series["Series4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10, 2);
    Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(20, 5);

    Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(10, 3);
    Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(20, 6);

    Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(10, 5);
    Chart.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(20, 8);

    Chart.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY(10, 12);
    Chart.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY(20, 14);

    Chart.Titles.Add("My Title1");
}
```

Comment: when is Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart called?

Comment: On button click. Did I create the chart the right way?

Comment: Looks ok but without the data it is hard to tell. Are x and y data numbers?

Comment: yes. Is there something else that I need to do after adding my points?

Comment: Not really. Are the Axes visible? Is there a legend and titles? If you give it a Color, can you see the ChartArea?

Comment: The axes are net visible. I haven't done all that yet. I'm not able to see the chart area.

Comment: I'm not able to see the title of the chart.

Comment: Hm, to see a Title you need to add one, maby like so : `Chart.Titles.Add("Title1");` - But as it stands I wonder if the Chartarea itself is created and attached correctly. Can you set a breakpoint to the Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart code?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to update active index of multiview control. change below code as below:

```
protected void FlexibleStraightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 vehicle = new Vehicle();
 OleDbConnection connection = null;
 string vehicleName = null;

 Get_Vehicle_Data(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

 Get_Tire_Data(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

 Get_Evaluation_Points(ref connection, ref vehicleName, ref vehicle);

 if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
 {
    Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
 }
 else if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
 {
    Generate_Flexible_ACR_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
 }
  // This line added
 MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
```

See output here. i deteriorate design but its working now.
[image]

Comment: your code didn't work in my app. I have a MultiView and my chart is in the second view. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried rendering with single view? Troubleshoot problem step by step. Try chart code with single view, if it works then try for multiview. This would be more logical for debugging or troubleshooting code

Comment: You are missing some another thing, I post this code after tried. You can see output image. Try this on simple aspx page with single button. You should update your complete code

Comment: I looked at an exact example for creating a chart and that's what I exactly did.

Comment: Multiview behave differently , you might investigate in this direction.

Comment: I know that it's not the multiview because the chart doesn't show up even when the chart is in single view.

Comment: @JonathanGeorgeVanSteenburg Answer updated with multiview. Refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_views.htm this for multiview

Comment: I updated my problem description. Also, the Aircraft Landing Gear button goes to the tab correctly.

Comment: @JonathanGeorgeVanSteenburg see now answer , i have updated and resolved your queries. close this thread.

Comment: Problem with another piece of code ..debug code precisely then ask question here with concrete problem